# time_t wrap around date

Tags: c, date

I'm trying to find out the date when the time will overflow the time_t value

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>

main(){
      time_t now,end;
      now=time(NULL);
      end=LONG_MAX;
      printf("Current date : %s\n",ctime(&now));
      printf("Date of death : %s\n",ctime(&end));
}
```

I found out that on my system time_t is 8 bytes like LONG_MAX. When I run it I get:

Current date : Sun Feb 1 17:29:09 2015 and, End Date of death : (null)
 but when I set `end=INT_MAX;` I get Date of Death : Tue Jan 05:14:07 2038 so **why do I get (null) with LONG_MAX? and not a normal date**

Comment: time_t is signed (and 32bit int in size) so the max time is 0x7fffffff.  (the jan 05:14:07 2038.   More modern RealTimeClock hardware will use a 64 bit counter, but the libc functions have not yet progressed past the 32bit time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

64-bit long would have the wraparound at somewhere around the year 292,277,026,596, which is ~20 times the current age of the universe from now. As the Earth's rotation would be unlikely to hold until at that time, and neither would people really care much, at that time it is very apt to return `(null)`.

---

Joking aside most probably the real reason is that the `ctime` algorithm might use `localtime` to convert `time_t` to broken-down time, and that uses `int` for the year value.

---

The following python script can be used to find the maximum value of `time_t` for which `ctime` does not throw an exception (it is a thin wrapper over the libc `ctime`, implementation in C is left as an exercise for the reader):

```py
import time

t = 0
for i in range(56, -1, -1):
    try:
        newt = t + (2 << i)
        time.ctime(newt)
        t = newt
    except ValueError:
        pass

print("Maximum value", bin(t))
print("Date at maximum", time.ctime(t))
```

The code outputs on my computer, glibc 2.19:

```
Maximum value 0b11110000110000101001110110000110100010111110000101011010
Date at maximum Tue Dec 31 23:59:52 2147483647
```

2147483647 is 2 ^ 31 - 1.